# convert png files to pdf with Bash?

Tags: bash

```
for f in find *.png; do convert "$f" "$f".pdf; done
```

This is what I have to find the png files in the directory and convert them to pdf, but I get errors. What is a better way to do this in Bash?

```
convert: unable to open image `find': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2705.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: no images defined `find.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3257.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in just one directory and not requiring find, you can do the following:

```
for i in *.png; do convert "$i" "${i%.png}.pdf"; done
```

which uses the shell globbing to find your files. Note the variable substitution to convert from a png to a pdf extension.

Otherwise it's more complicated. I think your `find` args are not correct. I would try:

```
find . -name \*.png
```

Note that I specify the starting directory (.) and then the name pattern (via -name). You need to *escape* the glob (asterisk) such that the shell doesn't expand it, and instead passes it directly to `find`.

Now, you can then execute `find` in a [subshell](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/What_is_a_Subshell%3F), and then use the results.

e.g.

```
for f in $(find . -name \*.png); do convert "$f" "$f".pdf; done
```

Note the $(...) which executes the subshell and makes the output available.

If your filenames contain whitespace, the shell may split on this and cause you further problems. If this is the case there are a number of options presented [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html)

Comment: I guess you should add an extension stripping step because the way the script is, you are going to have files named like `file.png.pdf`. Maybe `"${f%%.png}.pdf"`.

Comment: That's a good point. There are var substitution options on bash for this - see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: Though probably the OP simply means `for f in *.png`